# Entity Framework Migration Cascading Delete Warning

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have two classes that relate to one another (one-to-many) and I thought I had the properties setup correctly, but when I run the `Update-Database` command for my migration, I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.ParentEnrollment_dbo.CellGroup_CellGroupID' on table
>   'ParentEnrollment' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

My two classes:

```
[Table("CellGroup")]
public class CellGroup : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid AcademicYearID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AcademicYearID")]
    public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }

    public Guid LeaderID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LeaderID")]
    public virtual Parent Leader { get; set; }

    public Guid PreviousGroupID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreviousGroupID")]
    public virtual CellGroup PreviousGroup { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MaximumSize { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ParentEnrollment> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Table("ParentEnrollment")]
public class ParentEnrollment : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid ParentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public Guid AcademicYearID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AcademicYearID")]
    public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }

    public bool FirstTimeEnrolling { get; set; }

    public string HSLDAAccountNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime HSLDARenewalDate { get; set; }

    public string CurrentChurch { get; set; }

    public string CurrentChurchContact { get; set; }

    public string CurrentChurchPhone { get; set; }

    public Guid CellGroupID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CellGroupID")]
    public virtual CellGroup CellGroup { get; set; }

    public bool VolunteerBuyOut { get; set; }

    public Guid VolunteerPositionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VolunteerPositionID")]
    public virtual VolunteerPosition VolunteerPosition { get; set; }

    public string VolunteerPositionNotes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentEnrollment> StudentEnrollments { get; set; }
}
```

I only have the Parents property on the CellGroup class so I can easily access the list of enrollments in that cell group.  I tried to remove the property to see if it cleared up the warning/error, but it did not.  Can someone spot where I have gone wrong with my model(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error says that you cannot introduce a foreign key from table `ParentEnrollment` to table `CellGroup` that has cascading delete enabled, because this will create multiple cascade paths, which is not allowed on SQL Server.

According to the code you posted both tables have relations to a table `Parent` as well as `AcademicYear`, which are on non nullable FK columns, so EF will enable cascading on delete by default. With another FK from `ParentEnrollment` to `CellGroup` there would be multiple cascade paths, e.g. `Parent` to `CellGroup` to `ParentEnrollment` and `Parent` to `ParentEnrollment`, and this is causing your error. Removing the `Parent` property won't solve this because there still is the same cascading path problem starting from table `AcademicYear`.

So you have to disable cascading delete for your foreign key, which has to be done using Fluent API in your DbContext like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ParentEnrollment>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.CellGroup)
                .WithMany(m => m.Parents)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.CellGroupID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks so much.  Personally, I think my model structure might be off, but this is a great way of unwiring the cascading delete.

Comment: Althought that resolved the warning, it does not solve a problem I'm thinking with my model.  I will post another question with details.